# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

While updating i want to select the value of route from the another table when i try to do this it showing  `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`

This is my code:

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxxxxxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$client_id=$_POST['clientid'];
$feild=$_POST['field'];
        $data= $_POST['value'];
        $rownum=$_POST['rowid'];  
        $sql="UPDATE $client_id SET ".$feild." = '".$data."' WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";

         print $sql;

        mysql_query($sql);  


//Select route from client Table

$sql_select="select route from $client_id WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";
mysql_query($sql_select);
 print $sql_select;
 print mysql_error();
$i=1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select))
{

    $route=$rows['route'];

}

?>
```

Please help me, thank in advance

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
see url : http://us1.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this:

```
$sql_select="select route from $client_id WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";
$queryRes = mysql_query($sql_select);
 print $sql_select;
 print mysql_error();
$i=1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRes))
```

You need to provide #Resource returned from [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) function to [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc).

Note: Mysql_* are deprecated from PHP5.3. Hence should be avoided.

Comment: This code is susceptible to SQL injection; `$rownum` and `$client_id` must either be escaped or you should use prepared statements (and thus not use `mysql_` in the first place).

Comment: @Jack: agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql_select="select route from $client_id WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
 print $result;
 print mysql_error();
$i=1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $route=$rows['route'];

}
```